# How does user's emotion relate to ux?

Tags: emotion

I have been hearing a lot of emotional design and doing ux with user's emotion in mind. But how does this work and where does it fall under in the deliverables?

Comment: also, i see a lot of articles about emotional design. But their examples usually have to do with branding and UI. Not ux.

Answer (score 1):

### The experience map is everything

IME, a big piece of evaluating emotion happens during the [experience mapping](http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/the-anatomy-of-an-experience-map/) stage. You evaluate the users actions and state of mind at different points in their interaction with an organization, environment, or product.

It's less of a "deliverable" than it is something to reference (and update) continuously throughout the development and optimization of a product or service. Everything you develop should be considered in it's position on this map.

### Connect your feature to the map

It's intuitive for most experienced designers, but this is a formal way of designing the solution in the context of the user's needs. It goes beyond designing features for personas, extending it with the persona's context. And context should always include an emotional component.

- Is the user in a positive or negative state?
- What other things are on their mind?
- How can your new `x` improve that state?

Answer (score 0):

**Emotional Design is nothing new**, just a *relatively hip* thing to name something that has been being done for decades.

Depending on the area of development, *emotional design* applies to different UX aspects. For example, in web/digital design, it is mostly an UI concept, while in physical products the relations vary, including *shape, sound, light, texture* and so on. Thus, it's easy to see the deliverables will be different and the moment of the UX process when emotional design concepts are applied will vary as well.

For the more modern approach to emotional design, and in a certain way the more accepted voice about **emotional design in UX** you can watch this [TED talk by Don Norman](http://www.ted.com/talks/don_norman_on_design_and_emotion). It's more focused to physical (it's 13 years old) but its three emotional cues

- visceral
- behavioral
- reflective

still apply in modern digital media

Comment: Don Norman wrote a book called 'Emotional Design' (2004)

Comment: yes I know, I have it at 2 feet from what I'm now ;) Just wanted to provide something short, easy to understand and quite funny instead of "go read the book"